# Which site do I go to for configuration questions (i.e. setting up AWS environment variables on Amazon Linux)?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about setting AWS environment variables (i.e., `%env(AWS_KEY)% or %env(AWS_SECRET)`) for my project, and I know that Stack Overflow is only for programming issues—specifically code.

Which site can I ask configuration questions about web services on?

Comment: To get a finer bead on this - are you saying you don't know how to set environment variables _at all_, you don't know how to set environment variables for a given type of server (this looks like Microsoft), or you're not sure *what* to set those variables to?  The answer you seek depends on what you're doing here.

Comment: Hi Makoto, I updated my question.  It is specifically Amazon Linux.  I know there are tutorials out there on setting environment variables (i.e. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCajzETJG1Dj7FTDv7bMjAMw?feature=embeds_subscribe_title) but I don't know how to set AWS ones on an Amazon Linux server.  I already have the values that I need to set them to.

Comment: Why does this have two off-topic close votes when there’s a tag which exactly describes the question here?

Comment: My best guess would be [sf]. You can check their help section there: [on-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MTCoster, maybe due to third point of [that tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/site-recommendation/info).

Comment: It depends on the question. Are you using an API? The shell of the server? Are you automating stuff? This is for consumption of another program or you are using a helper? I suggest to post a draft of the would be question to figure it out.

Comment: @Sinatr This question falls within the scope of the 3rd point of the tag. That point is meant to exclude things wildly outside the realm of programming or computer management, e.g. bicycles or cooking or home improvement. Setting environment variables on a web-hosting service is heavily related to programming.

Comment: My problem is that if I ask the wrong question on Stack Overflow I risk it getting voted down and getting banned from the site.  So I have to be careful.  Braiam, I am setting the configuration variables for S3 access.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would strongly suggest [Server Fault](//serverfault.com) is your site. [Their Help Center says](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)

> managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks

Server Fault is for managing professional servers and AWS qualifies for that. There are also [similar questions to yours](https://serverfault.com/questions/910370/use-environment-variable-credentials-for-source-profile-with-aws-cli)

Comment: But please, first search for those similar questions to see if the answer already exists...

Comment: Unless culture at SF has changed over the last few years, they're really hostile to any entry level questions that should be part of the toolbox of anyone who wants to be a sysadmin.

Comment: @DanNeely I'd say we're pretty welcoming at ServerFault as long as it's about stuff you can encounter in a common-sense business environment. This also includes basic questions. But if a problem involved a router and two NAS devices at my home, I'd better ask at superuser.com, that's just how the communities partitioned themselves.